# Adding files to the Mac app

Tags: qt5, qmake

I'm trying to add my translation files (.qm files) to the mac app bundle.

This is not like the `INSTALL` phrase in the .pro file, I want this happen when I build the app.

I checked the document http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html here but it wasn't mentioned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
QM_FILES = $$files(*.qm)
QM_DEST_DIR = $${APP_NAME}.app/Contents/MacOS/translations

for(file, QM_FILES) {
    eval($${file}.depends = $$file)
    eval($${file}.target = $$QM_DEST_DIR/$$file)
    eval($${file}.commands = cp $$file $$QM_DEST_DIR/)

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $${file}
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$QM_DEST_DIR/$$file
}
```